# Best way of handling streamed data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, data-stream

I am currently working on a trading bot coded in Python. It listens to a websocket stream giving me a dict of OHLC data on 180 symbols (180 dicts of 7 values each second). Every minute I wanna calculate a bunch of indicators for each symbol. For that I need the data to be in Pandas df format. Additionally I wanna store a maximum of 600 dicts for each coin, sending the oldest 150 to a sqlite3 db whenever 600 is reached.

Right now I am storing the data in a dict of nested lists (e. g. `klines["BTCUSDT"][-1][0]` represents the timestamp of the most recent dict on symbol "BTCUSDT"). For the technical analysis with pandas-ta lib I transform the nested list of the symbol into a df. When a symbol's nested list reaches it maximum length I send `[:150]` to my db and `del [:150]` them right after.

As I need the data to be a df for ta I'd prefer to keep it as one the entire time. The problem is that appending to a df creates a new one leaving me with almost the same scenario as converting my list of dicts to a df every time I run ta.

Is there a better way of storing my data which suits my needs?

P.s.: Yes, I know the that premature optimization is the root of all evil? :D

Comment: you don't need to post the summary of whole task you are doing with bot. Also paste come code snippet also of the function/class where you are having so we can edit, or make suggestions also. Otherwise explanation is good.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was trying to emphasize the requirements of the data structure I am looking for.